# Private URLs with Assets or Compatibility with Protected Links

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic, s3, encryption

Does anyone know if Assets, when used in combination with Amazon S3 to store files can create "[signed URLs](http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-developer-guide/RESTAuthentication.html)" when serving up files on the front-end?

S3 provides a time limited signed URL option for ensuring links aren't guessed or shared and would generate a URL that looks something like this:

http://s3.amazonaws.com/quotes/nelson?AWSAccessKeyId=44CF9590006BF252F707&Expires=1141889120&Signature=vjbyPxybdZaNmGa%2ByT272YEAiv4%3D

If not, then is it possible to integrate with [Protected Links](http://www.intoeetive.com/docs/protected_links.html) so files can be uploaded via Safecracker on the front-end into an Assets field to create an entry and then later served back up on the front-end using Protected Links to provide a My Downloads area of secure links?

Has anyone successfully used that combination or know if the two would be compatible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that signed URLs are not an option in Assets at present but the good news is that IntoEEtive have confirmed that Protected Links should work perfectly well with Assets files so it should be possible to provide secure file links on the front-end with the help of this addon.

Comment: Being that you answered your own question, have you attempted this integration between the two?  Is it just as simple as replacing `{url}` with `{exp:protected_links:generate url="{url}" container="bucket-name" only_link="yes" storage="s3"}`?